# Why am I unable to edit Build.gradle and java files within android studio?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, project, edit

I have downloaded latest Android Studio 3.1 Canary and since then I am unable to edit files withing a project. Here is a screenshot of the project window. I am not using version control. Does anyone know why? 
Update - added a picture of the uneditable file build.gradle. I have verfied that the build.gradle file is not read only yet I was not able to edit it within Andoid Studio.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the underlying File system files are not Read-Only.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have checked each file and they are not read only.  Is there any setting in studio that can make the files non-editable? (Added a image)

Comment: @Ajay Are you able to edit other files? If not then Clean & Rebuild your project, if it doesn't work. Invalidate cache & Restart the studio. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: Can you load and save the files in a text-editor (notepad) ?, this will test user level permissions.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs in solving this crazy issue. I had done clean & rebuild multiple times but it did not work. I tried restarting studio and it did not work. Finally I shutdown the laptop & next time when I rebooted the laptop I see that Android Studio issue is resolved and I am able to edit the project. Just like old days when we restarted Windows 2000 server when nothing else worked! I think we should retain this post so people know that Restarting Machine is also one of the solutions for strange issues in Android Studio. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

"Invalidate cache & Restart the studio. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart." – Poras Bhardwaj

It works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32896466)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help but "Invalidate cache & Restart the studio" option does not helped to resolve issue in my case.

In my case IdeaVim editor was enabled so after disabling the same now I am able to edit my build.gradle file
[IdeaVim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2RkE.png)